# PowerBI Dates in period ignore filter/slicer measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

Im new to PBI and looking for some help with dax measures. Does anyone know  how to ignore date slicer in measure for dates in period?
I want to create one fixed summarized report next to flexible one with date slicer. So for my "fixed" report I failed to find information on how ignore date slicer that is used for other visualizations in same canvas.

I have tried

```
=CALCULATE([measure];ALL('Date'[Date]);DATESINPERIOD('Date'[Date];LASTDATE('Date'[Date]);-1; YEAR))
```

but I assume its incorrect as I don't get the results i want.

Comment: What does your data look like, what results do you get? What do you want them to look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to change the relationship on the modelling tab. Select the date slicer, navigate to manage relationships and then set the visuals to "No Relationship" that you do not want the slicer to effect. Saves time writing out DAX formulas if there not needed.